# RadHtmlPlaceholder issue

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I used the `RadHtmlPlaceholder` to display the HTML content in one window, but while I drag the window, the HTML content still display in the original place not in the window.
Can you please tell me the root cause of the issue?

```
<telerik:RadHtmlPlaceholder x:Name="htmlPlaceHolder" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  HtmlSource="{Binding Html}" Margin="0,0,0,8"/>
```